# Getting Fatal signal during recording a video

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera, segmentation-fault

I'm stuck on a problem for weeks now. Let me explain the context :

I'm trying to take Photos/Video with [this library](https://github.com/natario1/CameraView) (which is a good one no problem with that)

The problem now isn't the library, because I tried on 5 devices and photos/videos work every time.

The problem is the "device" I'm using , it's an "ELO-KIT-EloView-Engine" composed by a big screen, a small box running on Ubuntu 3.18.31 and an external camera. When I'm trying to take photos it works but when I want to record a video it crashes in less than 2 seconds in 100% of case, and I have this as Log :

```
--------- beginning of crash
07-11 09:19:52.777 F/libc    (  754): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xf2180000 in tid 2685 (recorder_looper)
07-11 09:19:52.780 F/ACodec  (  754): frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/ACodec.cpp:5778 CHECK((*it)->findInt32("type", &type)) failed.
07-11 09:19:52.781 F/libc    (  754): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 2700 (NPDecoder-CL)
07-11 09:19:52.781 I/libc    (  754): Another thread contacted debuggerd first; not contacting debuggerd.
07-11 09:19:52.784 W/        (  438): debuggerd: handling request: pid=754 uid=1013 gid=1005 tid=2685
07-11 09:19:52.862 F/DEBUG   ( 2703): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
07-11 09:19:52.862 F/DEBUG   ( 2703): Build fingerprint: 'Android/msm8953_64/msm8953_64:7.1.2/N2G47H/3.36.102:user/release-keys'
07-11 09:19:52.862 F/DEBUG   ( 2703): Revision: '0'
07-11 09:19:52.863 F/DEBUG   ( 2703): ABI: 'arm'
07-11 09:19:52.863 F/DEBUG   ( 2703): pid: 754, tid: 2685, name: recorder_looper  >>> /system/bin/mediaserver <<<
07-11 09:19:52.863 F/DEBUG   ( 2703): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xf2180000
07-11 09:19:52.863 F/DEBUG   ( 2703):     r0 f2180000  r1 f1462040  r2 0009ff80  r3 00000000
07-11 09:19:52.863 F/DEBUG   ( 2703):     r4 f1f28000  r5 00000000  r6 00000000  r7 00000000
07-11 09:19:52.863 F/DEBUG   ( 2703):     r8 f24838e0  r9 f3291ae8  sl 002f8000  fp f2e28200
07-11 09:19:52.863 F/DEBUG   ( 2703):     ip f5416624  sp f2483750  lr f55977cb  pc f53a6798  cpsr 200f0010
07-11 09:19:52.868 F/DEBUG   ( 2703): 
07-11 09:19:52.868 F/DEBUG   ( 2703): backtrace:
07-11 09:19:52.870 F/DEBUG   ( 2703):     #00 pc 00017798  /system/lib/libc.so (memcpy+108)
07-11 09:19:52.871 F/DEBUG   ( 2703):     #01 pc 000d57c7  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (_ZN7android16MediaCodecSource23feedEncoderInputBuffersEv+426)
07-11 09:19:52.871 F/DEBUG   ( 2703):     #02 pc 000d5d8f  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (_ZN7android16MediaCodecSource17onMessageReceivedERKNS_2spINS_8AMessageEEE+550)
07-11 09:19:52.871 F/DEBUG   ( 2703):     #03 pc 000d6715  /system/lib/libstagefright.so
07-11 09:19:52.871 F/DEBUG   ( 2703):     #04 pc 0000f461  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (_ZN7android8AHandler14deliverMessageERKNS_2spINS_8AMessageEEE+24)
07-11 09:19:52.871 F/DEBUG   ( 2703):     #05 pc 000116e1  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (_ZN7android8AMessage7deliverEv+60)
07-11 09:19:52.871 F/DEBUG   ( 2703):     #06 pc 0000ffc9  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (_ZN7android7ALooper4loopEv+380)
07-11 09:19:52.871 F/DEBUG   ( 2703):     #07 pc 0000e401  /system/lib/libutils.so (_ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+264)
07-11 09:19:52.871 F/DEBUG   ( 2703):     #08 pc 00046fe3  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+22)
07-11 09:19:52.871 F/DEBUG   ( 2703):     #09 pc 00019ced  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
07-11 09:19:53.074 W/NativeCrashListener( 1089): Couldn't find ProcessRecord for pid 754
07-11 09:19:53.080 I/BootReceiver( 1089): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_09 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
07-11 09:19:53.083 W/        (  438): debuggerd: resuming target 754
07-11 09:19:53.100 E/OMXNodeInstance(  744): !!! Observer died. Quickly, do something, ... anything...
07-11 09:19:53.101 E/OMXNodeInstance(  744): !!! Observer died. Quickly, do something, ... anything...
07-11 09:19:53.103 W/IMediaDeathNotifier( 1985): media server died
07-11 09:19:53.107 W/IMediaDeathNotifier(  740): media server died
07-11 09:19:53.107 W/IMediaDeathNotifier( 1089): media server died
07-11 09:19:53.107 E/MediaPlayer(  740): error (100, 0)
07-11 09:19:53.107 E/MediaPlayer( 1089): error (100, 0)
07-11 09:19:53.107 E/MediaPlayer( 1089): error (100, 0)
07-11 09:19:53.107 E/MediaPlayer(  740): error (100, 0)
07-11 09:19:53.108 E/MediaPlayer(  740): error (100, 0)
07-11 09:19:53.108 I/ServiceManager(  576): service 'media.player' died
07-11 09:19:53.108 I/ServiceManager(  576): service 'media.resource_manager' died
07-11 09:19:53.134 D/ContentLaunchService( 1266): Now checking playlist counter
07-11 09:19:53.134 D/ContentLaunchService( 1266): Content playlist not available at this time so check the default content
07-11 09:19:53.135 D/ContentPlaylistManager( 1266): clearCurrentPlaylistInfo: 
07-11 09:19:53.135 D/AppUtil ( 1266): setAttractLoopApkData: val >>  isPlaylistContent >> true
07-11 09:19:53.135 D/AppUtil ( 1266): setAttractLoopApkName: val >>  isPlaylistContent >> true
07-11 09:19:53.135 D/ActionsUtil( 1266): Sec since last touch = 0
07-11 09:19:53.135 D/ActionsUtil( 1266): Display Timer is ON, ignoring device default back light timings
07-11 09:19:53.155 D/ActionsUtil( 1266): PULSE_ACTION: OTA download NOT in progress
07-11 09:19:53.155 V/GlobalClass( 1266): isIdleTimeOutEnabled - idleTimeoutState [4]
07-11 09:19:53.155 V/ActionsUtil( 1266):  PULSE_ACTION: Check Athens idleness since [0]
07-11 09:19:53.155 V/ActionsUtil( 1266):  PULSE_ACTION: Check Device health [PUCK]
07-11 09:19:53.155 V/ActionsUtil( 1266):  PULSE_ACTION: Device idle since [0]
07-11 09:19:53.155 I/DeviceUtil( 1266):  lat 0
07-11 09:19:53.155 I/DeviceUtil( 1266):  long 0
07-11 09:19:53.155 I/DeviceUtil( 1266): Do not set 0 0 lat lon, this mean lat/lon is not configured from cloud yet
07-11 09:19:53.383 I/mediaserver( 2705): ServiceManager: 0xf2519780
07-11 09:19:53.385 E/ExtendedServiceUtils( 2705): player_type 6
07-11 09:19:53.385 E/ExtendedServiceUtils( 2705): Creating DashPlayer Factory
07-11 09:19:53.602 D/OverlayService( 1266): Overlay: handle masg
07-11 09:19:53.753 I/MSM-irqbalance(  845): Decided to move IRQ5 from CPU2 [P:0] to CPU4 [P:1] (banned)
07-11 09:19:53.754 I/MSM-irqbalance(  845): Decided to move IRQ3 from CPU3 [P:0] to CPU5 [P:1] (banned)
07-11 09:19:53.755 I/MSM-irqbalance(  845): Decided to move IRQ5 from CPU3 [P:0] to CPU7 [P:1] (banned)
07-11 09:19:53.755 I/MSM-irqbalance(  845): Decided to move IRQ5 from CPU0 [P:0] to CPU6 [P:1] (banned)
07-11 09:19:53.755 I/MSM-irqbalance(  845): Decided to move IRQ3 from CPU0 [P:0] to CPU4 [P:1] (banned)
07-11 09:19:53.756 I/MSM-irqbalance(  845): Decided to move IRQ5 from CPU1 [P:0] to CPU5 [P:1] (banned)
07-11 09:19:53.756 I/MSM-irqbalance(  845): Decided to move IRQ3 from CPU1 [P:0] to CPU7 [P:1] (banned)
07-11 09:19:54.658 W/QualcommUsbCamera(  740): Preview dump start.....
07-11 09:19:54.680 W/QualcommUsbCamera(  740): dump Successfull!!!
07-11 09:19:54.680 W/QualcommUsbCamera(  740): Preview dump end.....
07-11 09:19:55.212 E/OMX-VENC(  744): async_venc_message_thread interrupted to be exited
07-11 09:19:55.215 I/OMX-VENC(  744): Component Deinit
07-11 09:19:55.216 I/OMX-VENC(  744): Video encode perflock released
07-11 09:19:55.723 D/PowerManagerService( 1089): getScreenOffTimeoutLocked timeout: 2147483647
07-11 09:19:55.724 D/PowerManagerService( 1089): updateUserActivitySummaryLocked now: 93533
07-11 09:19:55.725 D/PowerManagerService( 1089): getScreenOffTimeoutLocked timeout: 2147483647
07-11 09:19:55.725 D/PowerManagerService( 1089): updateUserActivitySummaryLocked now: 93535
07-11 09:19:55.729 D/PowerManagerService( 1089): getScreenOffTimeoutLocked timeout: 2147483647
07-11 09:19:55.729 D/PowerManagerService( 1089): updateUserActivitySummaryLocked now: 93538
07-11 09:19:55.731 D/PowerManagerService( 1089): getScreenOffTimeoutLocked timeout: 2147483647
07-11 09:19:55.731 D/PowerManagerService( 1089): updateUserActivitySummaryLocked now: 93541
07-11 09:19:56.586 D/OverlayService( 1266): Overlay: handle masg
07-11 09:19:57.049 D/qdlights( 1089): read_brightness OK, value: 100, buffer[9]: 64
07-11 09:19:57.050 E/LightsService( 1089):  getBrightness light=255
07-11 09:19:57.651 I/EloSecureClient( 1266): MSG_GET_TEMP_VALUES value:= 0
07-11 09:19:57.651 I/EloSecureClient( 1266): MSG_GET_TOUCH_VALUES value
07-11 09:19:57.651 I/EloSecureClient( 1266): addTouchData() ja.length := 0
07-11 09:19:58.156 D/ActionsUtil( 1266): Sec since last touch = 5
07-11 09:19:58.156 D/ActionsUtil( 1266): Display Timer is ON, ignoring device default back light timings
07-11 09:19:58.182 D/ActionsUtil( 1266): PULSE_ACTION: OTA download NOT in progress
07-11 09:19:58.182 V/GlobalClass( 1266): isIdleTimeOutEnabled - idleTimeoutState [4]
07-11 09:19:58.182 V/ActionsUtil( 1266):  PULSE_ACTION: Check Athens idleness since [5]
07-11 09:19:58.182 V/ActionsUtil( 1266):  PULSE_ACTION: Check Device health [PUCK]
07-11 09:19:58.182 V/ActionsUtil( 1266):  PULSE_ACTION: Device idle since [5]
07-11 09:19:58.182 I/DeviceUtil( 1266):  lat 0
07-11 09:19:58.182 I/DeviceUtil( 1266):  long 0
07-11 09:19:58.182 I/DeviceUtil( 1266): Do not set 0 0 lat lon, this mean lat/lon is not configured from cloud yet
07-11 09:19:58.460 I/cnss-daemon(  772): RTM_NEWNEIGH message received: 28
07-11 09:19:58.460 E/cnss-daemon(  772): Stale or unreachable neighbors, ndm state: 4
07-11 09:19:58.753 I/MSM-irqbalance(  845): Decided to move IRQ5 from CPU2 [P:0] to CPU4 [P:1] (banned)
07-11 09:19:58.754 I/MSM-irqbalance(  845): Decided to move IRQ5 from CPU3 [P:0] to CPU5 [P:1] (banned)
07-11 09:19:58.754 I/MSM-irqbalance(  845): Decided to move IRQ5 from CPU0 [P:0] to CPU7 [P:1] (banned)
07-11 09:19:58.754 I/MSM-irqbalance(  845): Decided to move IRQ3 from CPU0 [P:0] to CPU6 [P:1] (banned)
07-11 09:19:58.755 I/MSM-irqbalance(  845): Decided to move IRQ5 from CPU1 [P:0] to CPU4 [P:1] (banned)
07-11 09:19:59.582 D/OverlayService( 1266): Overlay: handle masg
07-11 09:19:59.695 W/QualcommUsbCamera(  740): Preview dump start.....
07-11 09:19:59.772 W/QualcommUsbCamera(  740): dump Successfull!!!
07-11 09:19:59.772 W/QualcommUsbCamera(  740): Preview dump end.....
07-11 09:20:00.001 D/PowerManagerService( 1089): getScreenOffTimeoutLocked timeout: 2147483647
07-11 09:20:00.001 D/PowerManagerService( 1089): updateUserActivitySummaryLocked now: 97810
07-11 09:20:00.002 D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor( 1249): received broadcast android.intent.action.TIME_TICK
07-11 09:20:00.002 D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor( 1249): handleTimeUpdate
07-11 09:20:00.081 D/PowerManagerService( 1089): getScreenOffTimeoutLocked timeout: 2147483647
07-11 09:20:00.081 D/PowerManagerService( 1089): updateUserActivitySummaryLocked now: 97890
07-11 09:20:02.210 D/qdlights( 1089): read_brightness OK, value: 100, buffer[9]: 64
07-11 09:20:02.210 E/LightsService( 1089):  getBrightness light=255
07-11 09:20:02.586 D/OverlayService( 1266): Overlay: handle masg
07-11 09:20:02.657 I/EloSecureClient( 1266): MSG_GET_TEMP_VALUES value:= 0
07-11 09:20:02.657 I/EloSecureClient( 1266): MSG_GET_TOUCH_VALUES value
07-11 09:20:02.657 I/EloSecureClient( 1266): addTouchData() ja.length := 0
07-11 09:20:03.183 D/ActionsUtil( 1266): Sec since last touch = 10
07-11 09:20:03.183 D/ActionsUtil( 1266): Display Timer is ON, ignoring device default back light timings
07-11 09:20:03.215 D/ActionsUtil( 1266): PULSE_ACTION: OTA download NOT in progress
07-11 09:20:03.215 V/GlobalClass( 1266): isIdleTimeOutEnabled - idleTimeoutState [4]
07-11 09:20:03.215 V/ActionsUtil( 1266):  PULSE_ACTION: Check Athens idleness since [10]
07-11 09:20:03.215 V/ActionsUtil( 1266):  PULSE_ACTION: Check Device health [PUCK]
07-11 09:20:03.215 V/ActionsUtil( 1266):  PULSE_ACTION: Device idle since [10]
07-11 09:20:03.215 I/DeviceUtil( 1266):  lat 0
07-11 09:20:03.215 I/DeviceUtil( 1266):  long 0
07-11 09:20:03.215 I/DeviceUtil( 1266): Do not set 0 0 lat lon, this mean lat/lon is not configured from cloud yet
07-11 09:20:03.755 I/MSM-irqbalance(  845): Decided to move IRQ5 from CPU2 [P:0] to CPU4 [P:1] (banned)
07-11 09:20:03.756 I/MSM-irqbalance(  845): Decided to move IRQ5 from CPU3 [P:0] to CPU5 [P:1] (banned)
07-11 09:20:03.756 I/MSM-irqbalance(  845): Decided to move IRQ5 from CPU0 [P:0] to CPU7 [P:1] (banned)
07-11 09:20:03.757 I/MSM-irqbalance(  845): Decided to move IRQ5 from CPU1 [P:0] to CPU6 [P:1] (banned)
07-11 09:20:04.601 D/PowerManagerService( 1089): getScreenOffTimeoutLocked timeout: 2147483647
07-11 09:20:04.601 D/PowerManagerService( 1089): updateUserActivitySummaryLocked now: 102410
07-11 09:20:04.602 D/ELOPeripheralService( 1089): mCatchAllEvents: false
07-11 09:20:04.603 D/WindowManager( 1089): KEYCODE_HOME
07-11 09:20:04.603 D/WindowManager( 1089): Down
07-11 09:20:04.603 D/WindowManager( 1089): Launch default athens app
07-11 09:20:04.604 I/ActivityManager( 1089): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.elo.homelauncher cmp=com.elo.homelauncher/.HomeScreen} from uid 1000 on display 0
07-11 09:20:04.609 D/ActivityTrigger( 1089): ActivityTrigger activityPauseTrigger 
07-11 09:20:04.610 D/PowerManagerService( 1089): getScreenOffTimeoutLocked timeout: 2147483647
07-11 09:20:04.610 D/PowerManagerService( 1089): updateUserActivitySummaryLocked now: 102420
07-11 09:20:04.611 I/CameraController( 1985): Stop: posting runnable. State: STATE_STARTED
07-11 09:20:04.612 I/CameraController( 1985): Stop: posting runnable. State: STATE_STARTED
07-11 09:20:04.613 I/CameraController( 1985): Stop: executing. State: STATE_STARTED
07-11 09:20:04.613 I/CameraController( 1985): Stop: about to call onStop()
07-11 09:20:04.613 I/Camera1 ( 1985): onStop: About to clean up.
07-11 09:20:04.613 I/Camera1 ( 1985): onStop: Clean up. Ending video.
07-11 09:20:04.613 I/Camera1 ( 1985): endVideoImmediately: is capturing: true
```

I really hope that someone has a solution, It can be a material problem too, I know that the native camera application doesn't work well every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved !!

With the library that I use , I can change VideoQuality .

And the "device" just doesn't support 480p (which means no sense lol) , I have to put quality value to "highest" ( so 720p, or 1080p ).

If I don't set VideoQuality , the DEFAULT quality is 480p and then it doesn't work

On the native Camera , when I change quality vidéo , I don't have 480p choice.